# Is "fasciae" related to "fascism"?

Tags: etymology, nouns

Somebody used *fasciae* in a game I was playing (it was the bundle of sticks or twigs carried by Roman consuls as symbols of their authority).  Can anyone tell me if it is related to *fascism* as a word?

Comment: [etymonline gives (under *fascist*)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fascist): "*Fasci* "groups of men organized for political purposes" had been a feature of Sicily since c.1895, and the 20c. totalitatrian sense probably came directly from this, but influenced by the Roman *fasces*, which became the party symbol." See also [*fasces*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fasces) which confirms the connection.

Comment: Not strictly an answer, but perhaps interesting: biology uses the term "fascia" (i.e., bundle or grouping) to refer to the [sheath of connective tissue](http://www.selfcare4rsi.com/fascia.html) that wraps each muscle fiber.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, the terms are related.  Dictionary.com says that [*fasciae*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fasciae) comes from Latin for band, bandage; "akin to *[fasces](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fasces)*".  The origin of *[fascism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fascism)* is given as:

> ***Origin:*** 1915–20; < Italian *fascismo*, equivalent to *fasc(io)* bundle, political group (see *fasces*) + *-ismo -ism*

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fascism#Etymology) explains the connection:

> The term *fascismo* is derived from the Latin word *fasces*. The fasces, which consisted of a bundle of rods that were tied around an axe, was an ancient Roman symbol of the authority of the civic magistrate. They were carried by his lictors and could be used for corporal and capital punishment at his command. The word *fascismo* also relates to political organizations in Italy known as *fasci*, groups similar to guilds or syndicates.
>   The symbolism of the fasces suggested strength through unity: a single rod is easily broken, while the bundle is difficult to break.

[image]
<sub>(source: [curezone.com](http://curezone.com/upload/Members/new03/white.jpg))</sub>  [image]

Answer (score 2):

According to OED, the word fascism has its origins in the word 'fascis' meaning *bundle*. So, to answer your question, these two words are probably related

Answer (score 2):

Yes it comes from the Latin *fascis* meaning bundle. According to my father-in-law, who is Italian, the individual sticks of the *fascis* are easily broken; however as a bundle or fascis they can not.

#### Meaning: Strength United

So the Romans’ *fascis* was a symbol of strength. Similarly fascists have strength as a group.